# Does the symbol "&" in author list mean anything?

Tags: publications, authorship, author-order

Is writing *Author A & Author B* the same as writing *Author A, Author B* in the author list?

To make it clear, this question asks about formulating the author list in the author section when publishing a paper.

The field is computer science. Is there a way to signify that Author A is the first author?

Comment: Why do you think there is a "first author" rather than a true collaboration?

Comment: If authorship order matters in your subfield (as opposed to having alphabetical as the default), most likely Author A will be interpreted as the first author unless explicitly specified otherwise (e.g., using a footnote to indicate that first authorship is shared).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand and the comma mean essentially the same thing here. The one who is listed first is the first author. (In this case, Author A is the first author in both cases.)

*Clarification*: The definition of "first author" that I am familiar with is the author who is listed first. In any list, there is always a first item; therefore, there is always one (and only one) first author. I am not familiar with using the term "first author" to mean "the one with the most significant contribution."

Comment: Mostly in CS we are happy with alphabetical listings.

Comment: @Buffy In theoretical CS only, I think?

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy, not only, actually, but maybe not universally either.

Comment: I think you are making an assumption that the authors do not intend. Ask them. Otherwise you may be making an error as well as an assumption.

Comment: The list of authors involves me in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> Is writing *Author A & Author B* the same as writing *Author A, Author B* in the author list? (when publishing a paper)

You don't have a choice, the journal's style guide will do it for you. In cases where there is a list and not a block (or otherwise separated), an ampersand will be used for the last author in every case I'm aware of.

---

**Original answer**

In citation formats I'm familiar with (e.g. [APA](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/reference_list_author_authors.html)), using a comma with only two authors is never correct.

In other words, *Author A., Author B. (2020)* looks like a mistake, as if the third author (who would be separated by an *&*) were missing.

It makes no difference with regards to who is the "first" author.

Comment: Citation is not what the question is about, but it is a nice addition.

Comment: @user2679290 Oh, did you mean writing it that way in the references? My point would hold, it would still look like an error.

Comment: No, I meant writing like this in the author section of a paper.

Comment: @user2679290 Oh I see. You don't have a choice, it follows the journal's guidelines in any case (some don't have lists, and use blocks, where your question would be nonsensical).